# How to work around passing function as argument in Bigquery UDF?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

### Here is my issue:

How to work around passing a function as an argument in Bigquery UDF?

I want to create a bigquery UDFs library from two set of private functions:

- functionA, functionB, functionC
- function1, function2, function3

I want to expose mixin UDFs build from each combination of functions from the two sets.

I want to avoid code duplication in my source code.

### Until now the two solutions I have found are:

**Solution 1:**

Using a unique public UDF with two string parameters and a switch case inside the function.

For instance:

```
mypublic_UDF(*args, "functionA", "function1")
mypublic_UDF(*args, "functionA", "function3")
mypublic_UDF(*args, "functionB", "function1")
```

However, this solution does not benefit from bigquery SQL introspection, pre-run error, and warning checks, and involves parsing parameters for each row.

---

**Solution 2:**

Using a deployment script that instantiates each case in a new function

For instance:

```
mypublic_UDF_functionA_function1(*args)
mypublic_UDF_functionA_function3(*args)
mypublic_UDF_functionB_function1(*args)
```

However, this solution needs more logic to deploy the script and generate a lot of functions.

---

### Is there a preferred / best solution?

### EDIT:

My code is too complex to show here but here is a concrete example.

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION functionA (myint NUMERIC)
AS (IF( mod(myint,3)=1, myint, NULL));

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION functionB (myint NUMERIC)
AS (IF( mod(myint,4)>3, myint, NULL));

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION functionC (myint NUMERIC)
AS (IF( mod(myint*myint-1,5)=0, myint, NULL));

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION function1 (myint NUMERIC)
AS (SQRT(ABS(myint)));

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION function2 (myint NUMERIC)
AS (LEAST(GREATEST(myint,-1),1));

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION function3 (myint NUMERIC)
AS (1/GREATEST(myint,1));

--------------------------------------------------------
-- SOLUTION 1
--------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION first_functionset
(myint NUMERIC, mytype STRING)
AS (
    CASE mytype
        WHEN 'functionA' THEN functionA(myint)
        WHEN 'functionB' THEN functionB(myint)
        WHEN 'functionC' THEN functionC(myint)
        ELSE ERROR('Unknown function name')
    END
);


CREATE TEMP FUNCTION second_functionset
(myint NUMERIC, mytype STRING)
AS (
    CASE mytype
        WHEN 'function1' THEN function1(myint)
        WHEN 'function2' THEN function2(myint)
        WHEN 'function3' THEN function3(myint)
        ELSE ERROR('Unknown function name')
    END
);

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION mypublic_UDF
(myarray ARRAY<INT64>, param1 STRING, param2 STRING)
AS ((SELECT array_agg(first_functionset(second_functionset(x,param2),param1) IGNORE NULLS)
from
unnest(myarray) x
));

--------------------------------------------------------
-- SOLUTION 2
--------------------------------------------------------


CREATE TEMP FUNCTION mypublic_UDF_functionA_function1
(myarray ARRAY<INT64>)
AS ((SELECT array_agg(functionA(function1(x)) IGNORE NULLS)
from
unnest(myarray) x
));

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION mypublic_UDF_functionA_function2
(myarray ARRAY<INT64>)
AS ((SELECT array_agg(functionA(function2(x)) IGNORE NULLS)
from
unnest(myarray) x
));

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION mypublic_UDF_functionA_function3
(myarray ARRAY<INT64>)
AS ((SELECT array_agg(functionA(function3(x)) IGNORE NULLS)
from
unnest(myarray) x
));

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION mypublic_UDF_functionB_function1
(myarray ARRAY<INT64>)
AS ((SELECT array_agg(functionB(function1(x)) IGNORE NULLS)
from
unnest(myarray) x
));

-- and so on


Select
-- SOLUTION 1
mypublic_UDF(GENERATE_ARRAY(0,100), 'functionA', 'function1'),
mypublic_UDF(GENERATE_ARRAY(0,100), 'functionA', 'function3'),
mypublic_UDF(GENERATE_ARRAY(0,100), 'functionB', 'function1'),
-- SOLUTION 2
mypublic_UDF_functionA_function1(GENERATE_ARRAY(0,100)),
mypublic_UDF_functionA_function3(GENERATE_ARRAY(0,100)),
mypublic_UDF_functionB_function1(GENERATE_ARRAY(0,100)),
```

Answer (score 0):

It would go for *Solution 1*: one function with different parameters. However, readability is also important. Could you put the query for each of your 6 inner functions into separated UDFs? The the main `mypublic_UDF` could always call two of them.

Feel free to give insided in your UDF, I will add this answer for improving the *bigquery SQL introspection*.